# Matching several different email address formats in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

We'd like to allow several different formats for people to paste email addresses into our app, those being:

```
1. foo@bar.com
2. "Foo Bar" <foo@bar.com>
3. Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
```

Is there a good Javascript regular expression which can take any one of those 3 and give the email address, as well as the leading name if it exists? These seem to be the format users are copy/pasting into the app currently (we're only supporting the first right now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I might have got something!  It can definitely be improved, but give me a moment to defend it before you start suggesting changes.  Here's the regex:

```
/^(?:("{0,1})(\w+ \w+)\1 <([^@ ]+@[^@ ]+\.[^@. ]+)>|([^@ ]+@[^@ ]+\.[^@. ]+))$/
```

Let me explain what it does.  The first `^(?:` says that the text must start at the beginning of the field and that the next group will not be captured in a backreference.  We then start an optional item.  This must be done since we want to require either 0 or 2 `"`, and 0 or 2 `<` marks.  The first part of the optional item (before the `|` bar) deals with cases 2 and 3.

**Cases 2 and 3:**

The `("{0,1})` captures whether or not there is a quotation mark at the beginning.  Then we use the`(\w+ \w+)` to require a first name and a second name, separated by a space, in cases 2 and 3.  The parentheses around them capture them into a backreference so that you can get the value of the name later.  Then comes the `\1` - this is the backreference from the quotation marks earlier.  It says that if you used quotation marks at the beginning of the name, you must use them at the end of the name too.  Next up, the `<` says that the email address in cases 2 and 3 must be separated by a space from the name or ending quotation mark and must begin with a less-than sign. Finally, we have the regex for the email!  This is the same for all cases.  It is surrounded by parentheses to create a backreference.  The `[^@ ]+@` ensures that it must not have an @ symbol or space before the actual @ symbol.  The following `[^@ ]+\.` does the same with the period after the @ symbol, and the trailing `[^@. ]+` ensures the same is true after the period.  We then have a closing parenthesis to end the backreference to the email address, and a `>` symbol because this is still for cases 2 and 3, which require one.

**Case 1:**

We then get to the `|` pipe, which specifies that we've gotten to the other option in the regex.  If the format of the text did not match the opening conditions for cases 2 and 3, the regex checks to see if it's just a plain email address (case 1).  The regex here is the same as the one inbetween the `<>` symbols in cases 2 and 3 - it matches a valid email address and creates a backreference.

### **Valid formats:**

Here's an incomplete list of formats that work:

```
foo@bar.com
foo1.foo2@bar.com
foo1.foo2@bar1.bar2.com
Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
"Foo Bar" <foo@bar.com>
foo bar <site1.site2@test1.test2.com>
"foo bar" <site1.site2@test1.test2.com>
```

---

## [**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/zkyEC/)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to to keep email validation simplified to this regex:

```
/^(?:([^<]*)<)?([^@]+@[^.@]+\.[^@>]+)>?$/
```

Also check this very good code Google project to validate emails: http://code.google.com/p/isemail/

[Live Demo of above regex](http://www.rubular.com/r/Qoh1AAGhCI)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer isn't it, given you've completely ignored what the OP asked? Also your suggested regex will accept things like `me@@@@something....com...` and `one@two@three.com.`

Comment: @nnnnnn: Had I not provided a working regex for OP's question it would have been a comment. IMHO an email validation regex can be really daunting and even then it can fail sometimes so its better to stick to a simplified regex.

Comment: But your regex doesn't actually work...and OP didn't say "How do I validate email addresses?", he asked explicitly how to accept a string with a name and an address and extract the parts...

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't just about validation; it's about parsing the values out of the string. I need to get at least the email address and hopefully the name value as well from 2 and 3

Comment: @nnnnnn: I have actually modified my answer to not to accept more than one `@` and work with all the cases of OP's problem.

Comment: Very nice to see you responding to the comments, but your new regex still accepts multiple trailing `@` and `.` characters as long as they're after the first `.`, and still doesn't help the OP extract the name and email address separately.

Comment: @nnnnnn: I edited it further to capture name and email separately and it discards multiple `@` now. Though I still think there can be cases where this needs further tweaking but for the OP's examples it works fine.

Comment: OK, _now_ you're talking. The email address bit still isn't quite right as far as validating an address goes (still allows invalid use of `.`), but now that it gets the (optional) name and address separately I'm happy to give you a +1.

Comment: @nnnnnn: As I said earlier in my comment also that the actual regex to capture all the permutations of an email address can be very complex. And issue with `.` is that there can be multiple of them in an email address on both sides of `@` so regex needs to allow all that.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should grab the email in those 3 cases:

```
/<?(\w+@\w+\.\w+)/
```

Comment: This is close, but is there a way to grab the name as well?